# How Can Krusader Prepend the File Modification Date in ISO 8601 Format to the Original File Name?

Tags: format, rename, date, krusader

I want to prepend the file modification date in the form `YYYY-MM-DD_` to each existing filename (i.e. for files only, not for directories). I have seen that krusader has a multiple file renaming function which in principle allows prepending or appending such information to the existing filename and it can do this for all selected files.

However, since I use it in a Xubuntu 16.04.3 installation with German settings, the file dates are also displayed as `DD.MM.YYYY` and when I use the renaming function of krusader it also renames them that way.

When I use `[modificationdate;yyyy-MM-dd]_` in the part of the dialog specifying to prepend the filename on the second tab of the renaming dialog, it actually uses the modification date *but in addition it prepends the current date in the German locale format*, e.g.

```
09-02-20192019-01-04_old filename.jpg
```

This is complete nonsense, since one does such things to have files sorted by the date expressed in the filename!

How can I suppress the additional placement of today's date (in the example the first 10 characters `09-02-2019`)?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the first tab advanced mode (in German settings: "Fortgeschrittenen-Modus für Dateiname", strange usage of the German langugage!) of `krename`'s dialog. Just enter

```
[modificationdate;yyyy-MM-dd]_$
```

(this is case sensitive and the mixed lower- and upper case notation is really strange!)

[image: krename's dialog to prepend an iso8601-formatted modification date separated from the original filename by an underscore character]

Bingo!

Comment: "the mixed lower- and upper case notation is really strange" - Not so strange if you think about how *minutes* can be included in the format.